# Doctrine query: find entity that contains array in many-to-many association

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have entity `Service` and entity `Tag` which have many-to-many relationship. How can I get `Service` that have all of provided tags?

```
class Service{
      /**
      * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="serviceList")
      */
     private $tagList;
}


class Tag{
     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Service", inversedBy="tagList")
      * @ORM\JoinTable(name="tags_services")
      */
      private $serviceList;
}
```

So now in ServiceRepository I am doing this:

```
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('service');
 $qb->leftJoin('service.tagList', 'tag');
 $tagArray = explode(",", $tagList);
 $qb->expr()->in('tag.id', $tagArray);
```

But this query is returning Services that have at least on of the provided tags, not all of them.

Is it possible to implement this query with `$qb->expr()->*` method?

Comment: Maybe the `having` clause will help. Example: `$this->createQueryBuilder('service')->leftJoin('service.tagList', 'tag')->having('tag.id IN (:ids)')->setParameter('ids', explode(",", $tagList));`

Comment: As you discovered, IN selects any.  What you need to do is to foreach over $tagList and add a andWhere/setParameter for each tag so you end up with WHERE tag.id = ? AND tag.id = ? etc And always use parameters to protect against sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Cerad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1146363/cerad) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40420020/doctrine-query-find-entity-that-contains-array-in-many-to-many-association#comment68094240_40420020), you have to add a where/andWhere condition for each of the tags to retrieve the service(s) with all tags:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('service');
$qb->leftJoin('service.tagList', 'tag');
$tagArray = explode(",", $tagList);
$i = 0;
foreach($tagArray as $tag){
    if($i == 0){
        $qb->where('tag.id = :tag'.$i);
    } else {
        $qb->andWhere('tag.id = :tag'.$i);
    }
    $qb->setParameters('tag'.$i, $tag);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: @blahblah did it helped you?